# Ionic 3 radio button with 2 values

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework

I want to create a radio button that has 2 values, but I can't get it to work...

The whole form loop and all that works.

I need my ion-radio to have a `value=" {{helper?.userId}}` AND another value of `{{helper?.fullName}}`. Even better would be a secondary value.

It's all inside one form with 1 value called assign.

Here's the code:

```
<form [formGroup]="radioForm" (submit)="addNewEvent()">
                <ion-list mode="md" radio-group formControlName="assign" [(ngModel)]="radioForm.assign">
                    <ion-row>
                        <ion-col col-2>
                        </ion-col>
                        <ion-col col-20>
                            <p style="text-align: center; color: white; font-size: 17px;">Assign event</p>
                            <ion-item mode="md" class="calendarTransparentTwo">
                                <ion-label mode="md">Myself</ion-label>
                                <ion-radio color="lwhite" mode="md" value="{{this.userProfile.userId}}"></ion-radio>
                                <!-- <ion-radio color="lwhite" value="{{this.userProfile.fullName}}"></ion-radio> -->
                            </ion-item>

                            <ion-item mode="md" class="calendarTransparentTwo" *ngFor="let helper of helperList">
                                <ion-label mode="md">{{helper?.fullName}}</ion-label>
                                <ion-radio color="lwhite" value="{{helper?.userId}}"></ion-radio>
                                <!--<ion-radio color="lwhite" value="{{helper?.fullName}}"></ion-radio> -->
                            </ion-item>
                        </ion-col>
                        <ion-col col-2>
                        </ion-col>
                    </ion-row>
                </ion-list>
            </form>
```

Comment: Okay, I couldn't add the code. But my question is still very much relevant for me :)

Comment: Seeing the source from the edit (not yet approved by enough users though), I'm not exactly understanding what you need to do. can you please specify what is the exact desired result? It looks like as a regular radio button set. If that's a regular "radio form", please check the sample here: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/radio/RadioButton/ (use an ngModel and a radio-group if you want auomatic styling)